# How to select values from one field rdd only if it is present in second field of rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an rdd with 3 fields as mentioned below.

```
1,2,6
2,4,6
1,4,9
3,4,7
2,3,8
```

Now, from the above rdd, I want to get following rdd.

```
2,4,6
3,4,7
2,3,8
```

The resultant rdd does not have rows starting with 1, because 1 is nowhere in the second field in input rdd.

Comment: Can you provide the full types of the input and output RDD and also elaborate the rules how you want your data to be filtered and transformed.

Comment: Field and Field2 are string and Field3 is an Integer. I want only those rows in the output, in which value of Field1 is available in Field2. In the above example 2 and 3 are in Field2 of an rdd whereas 1 is nowhere in Field2

Comment: You need to update your question with a better explanation or a better example.

Comment: Seems clear to me. Select a row only if the value of the first field is the same as the value of the second field of any row. If the value of the first field is not found in in the second field of any row, don't select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if I understood correctly what you want to do, there are two ways:

1. Split your `RDD` into two, where first RDD contains unique values of "second field" and second RDD is has "first value" as a key.  Then join rdds together. The drawback of this approach is that `distinct` and `join` are slow operations.

   ```
   val r: RDD[(String, String, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     ("1", "2", 6),
     ("2", "4", 6),
     ("1", "4", 9),
     ("3", "4", 7),
     ("2", "3", 8)
   ))

   val uniqueValues: RDD[(String, Unit)] = r.map(x => x._2 -> ()).distinct
   val r1: RDD[(String, (String, String, Int))] = r.map(x => x._1 -> x)

   val result: RDD[(String, String, Int)] = r1.join(uniqueValues).map {case (_, (x, _)) => x}

   result.collect.foreach(println)
   ```
2. If your RDD is relatively small and `Set` of second values can fit completely in memory in all the nodes, then you can create that in-memory set as a first step, broadcast it to all nodes and then just filter your RDD:

   ```
   val r: RDD[(String, String, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     ("1", "2", 6),
     ("2", "4", 6),
     ("1", "4", 9),
     ("3", "4", 7),
     ("2", "3", 8)
   ))

   val uniqueValues = sc.broadcast(r.map(x => x._2).distinct.collect.toSet)

   val result: RDD[(String, String, Int)] = r.filter(x => uniqueValues.value.contains(x._1))

   result.collect.foreach(println)
   ```

Both examples output:

```
(2,4,6)
(2,3,8)
(3,4,7)
```